# Express (NodeJS) more cores vs. more nodes? (With Analysis and Examples)

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes

When it comes to running Express (NodeJS) in something like Kubernetes, would it be more cost effective to run with more cores and less nodes? Or more nodes with less cores each? (Assuming the cost of cpus/node is linear ex: 1 node with 4 cores = 2 nodes 2cores)

In terms of redundancy, more nodes seems the obvious answer.

However, in terms of cost effectiveness, less nodes seems better because with more nodes, you are paying more for overhead and less for running your app. Here is an example:

1 node with 4 cores costs $40/month, it is running:

- 10% Kubernetes overhead on one core
- 90% your app on one core and near 100% on others
  Therefore you are paying $40 for 90% + 3x100% = 390% your app

2 nodes with 2 cores each cost a total of $40/month running:

- 10% Kubernetes overhead on one core (PER NODE)
- 90% you app on one core and near 100% on other (PER NODE)
  Now you are paying $40 for 2 x (90% + 100%) = 2 x 190% = 380% your app

I am assuming balancing the 2 around like 4-8 cores is ideal so you aren't paying so much for each node, scaling nodes less often, and getting hight percentage of compute running your app per node. Is my logic right?

Edit: Math typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the node does not come empty, but it has to run some core apps like :

- kubelet
- kube-proxy
- container-runtime (docker, gVisor, or other)
- other daemonset.

Sometimes, 3 **large** VMs are better than 4 **medium** VMs in term of the best usage of capacity.

[image]

However, the main decider is the type of your workload (your apps):

- If your apps eats memory more than CPUs (Like Java Apps), you will need to choose Node of **[2CPU, 8GB]** is better than **[4CPUs, 8GB]**.
- If your apps eats CPUs more than memory (Like ML workload), you will need to choose the opposite; computing-optimized instances.
- The golden rule  is to calculate the **whole capacity** is better than looking into the individual capacity for each  node.

At the end, you need to consider not only cost effectiveness but also :

- Resilience
- HA
- Redundancy

Comment: That’s about what I thought. I was thinking more in terms of cpu too so it’s nice to see that awesome memory diagram!

Comment: you are welcome :) I also updated the answer to give you insight about the diversity of workload: some apps are computing-optimized and others are memory-optimized.. Matter that need to be considered. Good luck!